# JanusGraph IndexQuery vs RawQuery

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to implement a customized index backend for JanusGraph. In the IndexProvider interface, there are two types of queries: IndexQuery and RawQuery. What are the differences between them?

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure but I feel you may get more responses by creating an issue on the github page and asking there?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your suggestion.